# nodejs express-session connect-mongo circular dependancy

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use connect-mongo to store my express-session's however I am getting a depreciation warning on my server, but not my development machine.

The server is running Ubuntu 16.04, node v8.9.3
My dev machine is windows, node v8.9.4

the codebase is identicle. however on my server I am getting the following messages:

> (node:1789) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cyclic dependency detected
>
> (node:1789) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I admit I am a novice when it comes to node.

this is the code I am using:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession);

//Custom Modules Declarations
const settings = require('./config/app-settings');

//Open Connection to MongoDB
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(settings.settings.databaseUri);

//App Setup
const app = express();

// Express session
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'secret',
  //cookie: {maxAge: config.mongoDBSessionMaxAge * 1000},
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: connection,
    clear_interval: settings.settings.mongoDBSessionMaxAge
})
}));
```

please could you help me to remove the errors?

Comment: Where are you `require`'ing `expressSession`? I don't see that.

Comment: @jakerella Looks like I was too aggressive with my redacting of code

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything that jumps out at me on this one... could be something internal to mongo/mongoose, but hard to say. Obviously you're not doing any Promises directly, so that's my only guess. :/

Comment: @jakerella I have narrowed it down to the connect-mongo settings as if I take that out the messages dissapear. Would you be able to pointme to a guide where I could handle the promises directly? 

in the meantime I will disable the store

Comment: Other than diving into the `connect-mongo` source I'm really not sure. I have used mongo/mongoose, but not for session management (I use redis for that). But perhaps it has to do with you creating a MongoStore (which uses connect-mongo), and pass in a connection (mongoose) which maybe uses connect-mongo already?

Comment: hmm interesting, I will look at redis for session management to see if that fixes the issue.